# Are pixel values better for constraining photo containers?

Tags: image, html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

For responsive designs, I use `em` values instead of `px`. (Of course, `%` also comes into play.)

However, when considering *containers* of fluid photos (e.g. `div`, `figure`, etc.), layouts sometimes call that it has a `max-width` property in the CSS.

If this was declared in `em` (e.g. 700px/16px = 43.75em), then it could resize incorrectly depending on a user's browser settings and zoom.

Therefore, it seems that `px` values in CSS declarations are better-suited? But I am wary of using them now... alternatively, however, is such a precaution unfounded?

Comment: Surely if you set `img { max-width: 100% }` then if the container gets bigger than the image, the image stops growing? Also, if users change their zoom settings, wouldn't they expect the images to zoom too? Or am I misunderstanding the problem? Additionally, you'd need to test, but I *think* only IE adheres to pixels sizes when you change the text size setting. Others scale text accordingly.

Comment: Right, but in this case we'd want the container to stop growing bigger than the image. Should I adjust the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say set it in `em`, but accept that users can (and will) zoom in/out and/or change their base font size. That's just [some things you can't control](http://www.veen.com/jeff/archives/000791.html).

The best thing though, would be to set up some simple test cases and try it across a number of browsers / zoom / text-size settings.

Comment: I'd say that too, but, for example in the case of a [container with an image and caption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705616/how-to-get-img-to-be-the-same-width-as-figcaption), em values could stir up a mess where the image and caption would be mismatched with a non-16px base font size. I am sure there are other similar cases (hence why I asked this question broader than just that)

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, you'd probably want to use CSS which makes the figure into a `shrink-to-fit` element, e.g. `float` or `inline-block`. Alas neither are perfect solutions.

Comment: But I guess you're right, for non image solutions, `em` will be better where it's not possible to use `%`, marking as solved unless someone has any other suggestions :)