# How to get <img> to be the same width as <figcaption>?

Tags: image, html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

In a responsive design, how can the width of a `<figcaption>` be made to adjust according to the width of the `<img>`, but not exceed it?

```
 <section>    
    <figure>
        <img src="link.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

The [corresponding CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/XjthT/30/) only limits the `<img>` and not the `<figcaption>`, see:

[image]

How can the `<figcaption>` be constrained along with the `<img>`, **without** using `max-width: 200px` (or 12.5em) on the `<figure>` container?

---

Here are the important bits of CSS ([full on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjthT/30/)):

```
section figure {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto; /* to center it */
}

section figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; /* to make sure images behave like blocks */
}

section figure figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS please.

Comment: @Lokase, there was a JSFiddle link, but I've included the relevant CSS into the question as well (as per StackOverflow guidelines)

Comment: Thanks Baumr, didn't see the jsFiddle link on the first read through.  Is a javascript/jQuery solution out of the question?  Or do you only want to have a CSS solution?

Comment: Yeah, looking for a nice, simple cross-browser friendly CSS solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `max-width: 100%; display: inline-block;` (http://jsfiddle.net/vZpmq/1/) or `float: [left|right]` (http://jsfiddle.net/cdmU3/1/) on the `section` would cause it to shrink-to-fit it's content (and the box it's in). You might need to rework some other things to fit those changes, though.

Alternatively, try setting `width: 100%; height: auto;` on the img, and set the width on the `figure` element? http://jsfiddle.net/9yUsP/

(setting `height: auto;` on the `img` means it's retain it's aspect ratio regardless of `height` or `width` attributes set on the `img` element itself)

Comment: I updated your fiddle, setting `width: 100%; height: auto;` on the `img`, and putting a `max-width` on the figure. Seems to work, except the caption escapes when the window gets tiny (due to absolute positioning): http://jsfiddle.net/9yUsP/

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a method that'll avoid setting `max-width: 200px` (will work without the other changes you've made) — should I edit my question to emphasize? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't setting `figure { display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; }` and `figure img { max-width: 100%; }` achieve that? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/vZpmq/1/

Comment: Thanks! Floating left will un-center it (and will need a clearfix hack), inline-block actually works now (weird, apologies), but has issues with older browsers, and it'll need an additional container element taking away from semantics — wondering what's best...

Comment: At this point you're running into the limitations of CSS :( Do you really need a container? Adding a `<div>` around the outside won't affect semantics though; it literally doesn't mean anything (as I understand it). For IE6/7 add `zoom: 1;` to make `inline-block` work.

Comment: From what I understand, I'd have to use a browser-specific hack and set: `display: inline; zoom: 1;` for IE?

Comment: Correct. Conditional comments are the best way IMO, see: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Ah, and it'll need a container in order to make it not show inline with text as it does in your JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes, or else place it after a block-level element (i.e. anything with `display: block;`).

Comment: Found another problem, if [this is how IE6/7 will see it](http://jsfiddle.net/vZpmq/4/), then that's not great :P

Comment: I've tried it in IE7 compat mode (don't have a real IE7 to hand) and it looks fine (when I add the latest HTML5Shiv): http://jsfiddle.net/WDj4Y/

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks! I'll check that later on IE7/6. But I'm still wondering, then **maybe the `max-width: pixel value here` is the best/cleanest solution?** Despite each image width needing a specific `max-width`...

Comment: Whichever solution is easiest for the user adding the content to the site, IMO.