# Make <figcaption> render scrollbars when it's content's width exceeds the width of an <img> sibling

Tags: css, html, image

I'm trying to make the `<figcaption>` element render scrollbars when it's content's width exceeds the width of an `<img>` sibling, typically when the content is a long URL or a very long word.

The following code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534473/how-can-i-make-the-width-of-my-figcaption-match-the-width-of-the-img-inside/11652170#11652170) and it works with IE 11 and Edge 15 but not in Firefox 55 and Chrome 61:

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

figure {
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
  
figure figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/220x100" alt="">
  <figcaption>Long word in figure caption Lopadotemachoselachogaleokranioleipsanodrimhypotrimmatosilphioparaomelitokatak</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: What it looks like in IE 11 and Edge 15: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPIUa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705616/how-to-get-img-to-be-the-same-width-as-figcaption/13705865#13705865) which I applied to the code snippet in the original question:

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

figure img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

figure figcaption {
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/220x100" alt="">
  <figcaption>Long word in figure caption Lopadotemachoselachogaleokranioleipsanodrimhypotrimmatosilphioparaomelitokatak</figcaption>
</figure>
```